# Correlation to use for non-scale data( counts)

Tags: regression, correlation, nonparametric, count-data

In our college we run some extra non-required sessions that we hope help the students.  To decide whether they help, I wanted to correlate the number of sessions attended with the cumulative gpa of the students.  While the gpa is a real number that can be (nearly) divided infinitesimally, the count of sessions attended is just a count, it is either zero, 1, 2, 3, etc. so I'm wary of using Pearson correlation.

What would be the best test to use to decide whether the sessions helped?

Charting the data suggests the sessions help.

Here are the data:

```
Sessions    Mean GPA
Attnd

 - *0   2.578
   *1   2.691
   *2   2.849
   *3   2.915
   *4   3.268
   *5   3.081
   *6   2.928
   *7   2.969
   *8   3.023
   *9   3.026
   *10  3.391
```

Thanks

Comment: I tried to list the data, but it did not work well. Sorry.

Comment: (Just use the formatting icons available above the text box when you are writing your question.) It won't be possible to give much particular advice based on the summaries you have offered: at a minimum, showing the numbers of students corresponding to each row is needed.  Standard deviations of the GPA would help even more. Note, too, that what you can infer from such data is limited: you can demonstrate an *association*, but you will not be able to demonstrate a *causal relationship.*  (After all, maybe the smarter students tend to attend more sessions in the first place.)

Comment: @whuber: I do have for 155 students their actual GPA and the number of sessions attended.  Does that help you point me to the test to use?  And thanks for fixing the list.

Comment: It's a start, but what really is needed are counts of the numbers of grades contributing to each one of those GPAs. (Even better--much better--would be the standard deviations of each GPS, too.)  Small counts or large standard deviations imply large uncertainty and *vice versa*.  Any appropriate statistical test will need to account for those variations in uncertainty. I would anticipate that as the number of sessions increases, the counts tend to decrease, but that's not necessarily true in any particular dataset.

Comment: Do you mean for each student the grades in each subject:

Comment: Each one of your "mean GPA" figures appears to summarize a group of students.  If you wish to perform a good statistical analysis, then at a minimum you should report the standard deviation and count of each group in addition to its mean.  Another (less condensed) way to show these data would be to list all 155 students, giving the count of sessions attended and final grade for each one.

Comment: I can certainly do that.  I have that data.  I don't want you to do all the work though.  I was hoping there'd be a "use the Spearman XYZ test" kind of answer.

Comment: That's fine: I was principally concerned with ascertaining that you actually have such data available and with emphasizing that a good answer cannot be developed only with the kind of data you have shown.